# Padding 3 channel image with zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I'm reading images from a number of folders, then pad each folder

images with a predefined number of zeros so that all of the folders will

have same number of images . each image shape is (127,227,3 ) ,

```
 for file in allfiles:
            files.append(file) if ('.jpg' in file) else None
            samples = np.empty((127, 227,3))

    for file in files:
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(pth_upd,file))
            img=img.astype(np.float32)
            samples = np.append(samples, img, axis=0)
    print(samples.shape)

   pad_size=half_len-len(samples)       

   samples = np.pad(samples,(( pad_size,0),(0,0),(0,0)),mode='constant', constant_values=0) 

   f_name=format(folder)

  full_path ='C:/Users/sarmad/Documents/dev_test_of' + f_name
```

### I get this error :

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-14-da54323f81ce> in <module>
 58     pad_size=half_len-len(samples)
 59 
  samples = np.pad(samples,(( pad_size,0),(0,0), 
   (0,0)),mode='constant', constant_values=0)
   61 
   62     f_name=format(folder)

 ValueError: ((-44812, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)) cannot contain negative values.
```

Comment: could you tell us what is the half_len? because len(samples) probably is a very big number. what is your purpose when appending to sample? since shape changes i must ask.

Comment: half_len is the size of the largest folder for example 500-(current_number_of_images_in_folder) , I need to make pkls as use them as batches for keras

Comment: Your pad_size becomes negative, so check whether len(samples) gets too large.

Comment: @N.zay could you try 'pad_size=(half_len + 1) * 127  - len(samples)'. because as i understand the 'half_len' is the number of files. but your first dimension of the sample expanding by 127 with each append, which is giving the length of array. and the '+1' for the biggest directory. since the first zeros in samples counts as 127 in length. but you could be doing something wrong. what is the shape of the 'samples' you are trying to achieve.